# How do I summarise data from multiple files into batches of multiple files?

Tags: r, file

The file names my lab has contains the monkey ID, system number, date, and the task the data is for, and each file contains a header row. We would like to check their progress daily, so we’re interested in seeing if we can automate the daily summaries as much as possible using R. The way we are doing it with Excel is clunky and takes too much time. For a daily summary, we’d need to know what task(s) they worked on, how many trials they did (on each task), and their percentage correct (on each task).

I have figured out the coding script to determine the daily summaries but I’m having issues as right now the script only runs with one monkey and one data file. Ideally, I would like to have it so that I could effectively point the script at a folder with a bunch of data files from different monkeys and generate daily summaries. Here are some examples of the summaries I have generated:

```
7-255 Summary table:
 n_trials      correct      incorrect     task_name
    7           42.85714    57.14286     SHAPE2


H033 Summary table:
n_trials  correct   incorrect    task_name

  177   44.0678   55.9322       MTSseq
```

I have attached my coding script below:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#library(readr)

file <- "/Users/siddharthsatishchandran/R project/R project status 1/Data/H033.csv"

data_trials <- read_csv(file)
head(data_trials)

summary(data_trials)

n_trials <- length(data_trials$trial)

correct <- mean(data_trials$correct)*100
incorrect <- 100 - correct

df_trials_correct <- data.frame(n_trials = n_trials,
                            correct = correct,
                            incorrect = incorrect,
                            task_name = unique(data_trials$task_name))

df_trials_correct
```

Comment: (1) Do you want to read in multiple `.csv`-files? If yes: are they all located in the same directory? (2) If there are multiple tables, how does your expected output look like?

Comment: Hi, I would be reading in multiple CSV files all located in the same sub directory. Likely it would generate a series of summary tables related to each file and the idea would be to take a series of datasets that we gathered from individual monkeys and generate all of their individual summary tables.

Comment: So your `df_trials_correct` in your question is one of those summary tables? If yes: when you read in multiple files, you get multiple tables. How do you want to handle them? Stored in a list of tables?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```r
path <- "/Users/siddharthsatishchandran/R project/R project status 1/Data"

file_list <- list.files(
  path,
  pattern = "csv$"
  )

summary_tables <- list()

for (file in file_list) {
  data_trials <- read_csv(file.path(path, file))
  
  summary_tables[[files]] <- data.frame(
    n_trials = length(data_trials$trial),
    correct = mean(data_trials$correct)*100,
    incorrect = 100 - correct,
    task_name = unique(data_trials$task_name)
    )
}
```

Now you get a list of data.frames, each containing your desired information.

This could be "flattened" into a single data.frame using `bind_rows`:

```r
bind_rows(summary_tables, .id = "monkey_id")
```